# JQuery selector namespace

Tags: jquery, namespaces, selector

I am trying to target this node:

```
<ns1:image href="http://broadcast.lds.org/XML/LDSRadio/LDSRadio_EnduringItWell.jpg" />
```

from here (http://feeds.lds.org/EnduringItWell)

It works if I do this:

```
$(result).find('ns1\\:image').length
```

How can I write the selector so it selects it without 'ns1'? (because this 'ns1' can be something different)

I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
 $(result).find('\\:image').length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select it with direct selectors instead you can do,

```
$(result).find("*").filter(function(){
  return this.tagName.toLowerCase().indexOf(":image") > -1;
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/u33bxxxy/)